# MYSQL Max(column) where 2 tables have same column

Tags: php, mysql

My Tables are as follows:

```
books:
id | abbr | volume | name | 
1  |  GZ  | SLZT   | Gazo |
...  
vol1:
id | book | chapter | line
1  |  GZ  |   1     | "text..."
...
vol2:
id | book | chapter | line
1  |  SD  |   1     | "more..."
...
```

(the tables align at vol1.book = books.abbr, in this example I only show Vol1 matching.)

So, to find the last chapter in a book for volume 1 is simple. I do this:

```
SELECT MAX(chapter) FROM vol1, books WHERE vol1.book=books.abbr 
AND books.volume='SLZT' AND books.name ='Gazo';
```

which works fine. BUT, what if I wanted to include everything in vol2 into the same query?

I've tried:

```
Select Max(chapter) FROM vol1,vol2,books
WHERE (vol1.book=books.abbr OR vl2.book=books.abbr)
AND books.volume='SLZT' AND books.name = 'Gazo';
```

which of course gives me an error that says chapter is ambiguous as it is used twice.

Also, I will be making the values 'SLZT' and 'Gazo' in the example variables in the actual code.

So, essentially, I'd like to be able to type in any book/volume and find the value of the highest chapter, regardless of whether it is in vol1 or vol2.

hopefully I've crafted the question well enough to provide all the info needed. And thanks!

***Edit::***

Someone posted the following solution and it's close - the **strange** thing is that it disappeared from the answers! They suggested using *UNION*:

```
SELECT MAX(chapter) FROM vol1
JOIN books ON vol1.book = books.abbr
WHERE books.volume = 'SLZT' AND books.name = 'Gazo'
UNION
SELECT MAX(chapter) FROM vol2
JOIN books ON vol2.book = books.abbr
WHERE books.volume = 'SLZT' AND books.name = 'Gazo'
```

This gives me (for example):

```
MAX(chapter)
50
NULL
```

But how can I get it to return just the 50 value (i.e. the non-null value) of the table?

Comment: Any reason you don't just put both in one table, and have a volume column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(`vol1`.`Chapter` > `vol2`.`Chapter`,`vol1`.`Chapter`,`vol2`.`Chapter`) AS `Max` FROM ...
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm not sure I got the whole statement right so it didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select GREATEST(vl1.Max(Chapter),vl2.Max(Chapter)) FROM books 
left join vol1 on vl1.book=books.abbr
left join vol2 on vl2.book=books.abbr
WHERE  books.volume='SLZT' AND books.name = 'Gazo';
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, see edit in my post above where someone suggested UNION - that seems the closest.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should look at optimizing your db structure by combining 2 volume tables into one. It would make your query easier to write and probably faster. You really don't want to create a new table every time you import a book with more volumes than your current number of tables.

Comment: There would be no adding of books or volumes in this db it's a finished reference only work.